# Firebase Custom Password Reset Link

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I just upgraded my Firebase plan to Flame, which also allows me to create a custom action link URL. In the Firebase docs it only tells you how to change it from their console, but not really set anything up from my server-side. Is there any tutorials or templates that I can use for this?

I can't seem to find anything.

Help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no server-side code that you'll need to write for this. It's all client-side code that uses the Firebase JavaScript SDK. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Comment: I don't get it. I want to change the reset password link sent from my custom mail, to a custom URL containing my URL, and change the password from a browser. Is this possible?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen In the docs it says: "Specify the URL to your server's account management page. Two parameters, mode and oobCode, will be appended to the URL when emails are sent. For example: https://example.com/acctmgmt?mode=<action>&oobCode=<code>.". That's why I find it very strange that I don't need any type of files uploaded to my web server? I am currently creating an app, and I want the user to redirect to my appname.com/accountmanagement, instead of firebaseapp.google.com/accountmanagement. Does it still apply?

Comment: You can specify your own landing page: appname.com/accountmanagement in the Firebase console but you will need to implement that page following the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Comment: @bojeil Okay, now it's a bit more clear. However, do I need to upload any Firebase-content to my web server (configuration etc), or can I just simply 'copy paste' the content shown in the docs?

Comment: You don't need backend code. It can all be done on the client. The code shown in  the docs covers the logic but you have to implement the UI.